# Python : How to check that monotonicity was correctly applied in XGBoost?

Tags: python, xgboost

I tried to use the option of putting monotonic constraints in XGBboost (without using Scikit-Learn wrapper : see my previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43076451/how-to-enforce-monotonic-constraints-in-xgboost-with-scikitlearn))
but I now would like to check that this was correcly applied.

As this type of model is a kind of *black box*, I usually try to look at some KPI related with the overall accuracy of the model (logloss, RMSE, etc.) but not directly to the effect of each feature.

Is there an easy way (or alternatively complex one) to do so and then check that monotonicity was effectively applied ?

At this stage, what comes to my mind is 1/ to take one observation of the test set, 2/ to duplicate it - let's say 10 or 100 times - 3/ then to manually make vary one of the features for which monotonicity should apply 4/ to make of graph about the predicted values. That is not stragith forward (especially considering that I want to check it on ~25 features...) nor very robust (I do not change the values of the other features that are correlated to the one I am looking at).

Any suggestion is welcome !